# vbScript to save attachment using part of the subject as the file name

Tags: vbscript

I'm using vbScript to save an attachment received via email to a shared drive.  I am able to get the file to move as expected.  What I I cannot figure out is how to pull the date from the subject line and use it as part of the file name.

The email subject will read like this:

Company Extract 20160125

The file should then be named:  COM20160125.txt

```
    For Each objMailItem in objItems 'Handle each email
        For Each objAtt In objMailItem.Attachments 'Handle multiple attachments
            If objMailItem.Subject = |"COMPANY EXTRACT 2*" Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution:

```
 For Each objMailItem in objItems 'Handle each email
        For Each objAtt In objMailItem.Attachments 'Handle multiple attachments
             If InStr(objmailItem.Subject, "COMPANY EXTRACT 2") Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile NETWORK_SAVE_LOCATION & "COM" & Right(objmailItem.Subject,8) & ".txt"
```